# Finding certain percentages from function

Tags: php, function

I'm making a grade calculator where the user inputs their earned points, points possible, then its weight within the class. Afterwards it then calculates and prints the percentage earned for each portion along with its weight. Finally, it prints your total calculated score along with the letter grade. I'm able to print the very last line completely, along with each categories' weight, but I can't print out the percentage earned in each category

```
<?php
         $par_Earned = $_POST['earnedParticipation'];
         $par_Possible = $_POST['maxParticipation'];
         $par_Weight = $_POST['weightParticipation'];
         $q_Earned = $_POST['earnedQuiz'];
         $q_Possible = $_POST['maxQuiz'];
         $q_Weight = $_POST['weightQuiz'];
         $l_Earned = $_POST['earnedLab'];
         $l_Possible = $_POST['maxLab'];
         $l_Weight = $_POST['weightLab'];
         $p_Earned = $_POST['earnedPracticum'];
         $p_Possible = $_POST['maxPracticum'];
         $p_Weight = $_POST['weightPracticum'];


        function percentage($a,$b){
             $percent = ($a/$b)*100;
             return $percent;
            }

        function weightValue($c,$d,$e){
             $weight = (percentage($c,$d) * $e)/100 ;
             return $weight;
            }

        $parWeight = weightValue($par_Earned,$par_Possible,$par_Weight);
        $quizWeight = weightValue($q_Earned,$q_Possible,$q_Weight);
        $labWeight = weightValue($l_Earned,$l_Possible,$l_Weight);
        $pracWeight = weightValue($p_Earned,$p_Possible,$p_Weight);
        $total = $parWeight+$quizWeight+$labWeight+$pracWeight;

        function lettergrade($total) {
            if ($total >= 95) {
            $lettergrade = "A+";
            }
            else if ($total < 95 && $total >= 90 ) {
                $lettergrade = "A";
            }
            else if ($total < 90 && $total >= 85) {
                $lettergrade = "B+" ;
            }
            else if ($total < 85 && $total >= 80) {
                $lettergrade = "B" ;
            }
            else if ($total < 80 && $total >= 75) {
                $lettergrade = "C+" ;
            }
            else if ($total < 75 && $total >= 70) {
                $lettergrade = "C" ;
            }
            else if ($total < 70 && $total >= 60) {
                $lettergrade ="D" ;
            }
            else if ($total < 60 && $total >= 0) {
                $lettergrade = "F" ;
            }
            else {
                $lettergrade = "Grade is not valid";
            }
            return $lettergrade;
}
    echo "<p>You earned a X with a weighted value of " .$par_Weight. "% </p>";
    echo "<p>You earned a X with a weighted value of " .$q_Weight. "% </p>";
    echo "<p>You earned a X with a weighted value of " .$l_Weight. "% </p>";
    echo "<p>You earned a X with a weighted value of " .$p_Weight. "% </p>";
    echo "<p><b>Your final grade is " .$total. "%, which is a ".lettergrade($total)."</b></p>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you verify if you receive the $_POST data?

What is the result of

var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Yes I do receive it as I'm about to calculate the right end result. I just can't seem to pull out each percentage from the percentage function